# Display the shipping charges without clicking on "check" button

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, zipcode

visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html) , you can find shipping charges in view page , **image 1**:

[image]

enter " 110001" in textfield, click on "check" button in link2, it will show as above, now click on another product [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-medi-kid-8869.html) , you can see zip code "110001" is still present in text field. This is fine.

But for getting shipping charges, we have to **again** enter "check" button. what i need is without clicking on "check" button, **it should display the shipping charges once we open any product page link** for 2nd time.

**form.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isEnabled()): ?>

<div class="block block-shipping-estimate">
<img src ="http://sitename.com/media/font-100.png" height="35" width="70" class ="ikon">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getTitle(); ?></span></strong>
    </div>

    <div class="block-content">

    <p class="block-subtitle">

    <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getDes(); ?>
    </p>
    <ul class="shipping-estimation-form" id="shipping-estimation-form">
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('country')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Country') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect(
                            ($this->getFieldValue('country') ? $this->getFieldValue('country') : $this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry()),
                            'estimate[country_id]',
                            'estimate_country'
                        );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="estimate_country" name="estimate[country_id]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry())?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('region')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_region_id"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select id="estimate_region_id" name="estimate[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isFieldRequired('region') ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                        <option value=""><?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Please select an option') ?></option>
                    </select>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                   //<![CDATA[
                       $('estimate_region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getFieldValue('region_id')); ?>');
                   //]]>
                   </script>
                   <input type="text" id="estimate_region" name="estimate[region]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('region')) ?>"  title="<?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
               </div>
            </li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                new RegionUpdater('estimate_country', 'estimate_region', 'estimate_region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
            //]]>
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->isFieldVisible('city')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('City') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="estimate_city" type="text" name="estimate[city]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('city')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?>
            <li class="item">

                <label for="search"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?></label>
                <div class="search">

                    <input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('coupon_code')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_coupon_code"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Coupon Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_coupon_code" name="estimate[coupon_code]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('coupon_code')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('cart')): ?>
            <li class="item radio">
                <label for="estimate_cart_yes"><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Include Cart Items') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_yes" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" <?php if ($this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Yes') ?>
                    <input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_no" name="estimate[cart]" value="0" <?php if (!$this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /> <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('No') ?>
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php elseif ($this->useShoppingCart()):?>
            <input id="estimate_cart_yes" type="hidden" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" />
       <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('shipping-estimation-form');</script>
    <div class="actions">
        <span class="please-wait f-left" id="shipping-estimate-loading-message" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?>
        </span>
        <div class="f-right">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getButton(); ?>" 
            onclick="estimateProductShipping()" class="button">
            <span><span style ="font-size:11px; padding:5px;">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('CHECK') ?></span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="shipping-estimate-results" style="display:none">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function estimateProductShipping()
{
    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                    '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                    '#product_addtocart_form input',
                    '#product_addtocart_form select']);

    var validationResult = true;

    // Check the valid input
    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) {
        return;
    }

    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);
    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();
    new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
        parameters: parameters,
        onComplete: function() {
            $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
            $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
        }
    });

}
//]]>
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

**result.phtml**

```
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate block-shipping-results">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>
        <?php 
    echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getShiptitle(); 
        ?>
        </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
<?php if ($this->getResult()):?>
        <dl>
            <?php foreach ($this->getResult() as $code => $_rates): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <?php 
                            //  echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() 
                                ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php //echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getResult(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you should be able to do it by doing the following after the `estimateProductShipping()` JS function declaration (after the last `</script>` tag):

```
<?php if ($this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode'))): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            estimateProductShipping();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thus, if a value is already assigned, it will call the function when the window is loaded.

Comment: Its working now. but its taking some time to load shipping charge.

click [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) click on "check" button, than click [here] :
 [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-medi-kid-8869.html)

Comment: @BabyinMagento Works fine for me. It takes some time as it's waiting for the entire page to load. What you can do to make it faster is to only keep the `estimateProductShipping();` line in the script I pasted. The lines around it are mostly to ensure every needed resources have been loaded