# Restrict customer in checkout if zip codes are not from predefined zip code list

Tags: shipping-methods, zipcode

we are restricting the zip codes for custom shipping method....

for now we are facing problem as here :

[Display the shipping charges without clicking on "check" button](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106162/restrcit-zip-codes-for-custom-shipping-method-is-not-working-after-hide-the-ship)

so is there any other way we can allow only some zip codes and restrict other zip codes.

can we do restricting zip codes independent of shipping method

Comment: You can try extending `collectRates` method in class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping`. I believe this is the class responsible for collecting all the shipping rates. This way, you could achieve restricting methods on the basis of zip-codes globally.

Comment: @Prateek can you please post the answer with code for extending the collectrates method.

Comment: @Prateek before, you only helped me to restrict and allow only some zip codes for custom shipping method. now as we hide the shipping method, its giving problem in above link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with re-write of the core Shipping model. Inside your extension config, create a re-write of that model, and in your extended model file, the content will go something like this :

```
<?php
class Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
        $storeId = $request->getStoreId();
        if (!$request->getOrig()) {
            $request
                ->setCountryId(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID, $request->getStore()))
                ->setRegionId(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_REGION_ID, $request->getStore()))
                ->setCity(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY, $request->getStore()))
                ->setPostcode(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP, $request->getStore()));
        }

        $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
        $restrictedCodes = array(
            110001,
            110002
            );
        //restricted values. they can come from anywhere

        if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $limitCarrier = $request->getLimitCarrier();
        if (!$limitCarrier) {
            $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $storeId);

            foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
                $this->collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
            }
        } else {
            if (!is_array($limitCarrier)) {
                $limitCarrier = array($limitCarrier);
            }
            foreach ($limitCarrier as $carrierCode) {
                $carrierConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/' . $carrierCode, $storeId);
                if (!$carrierConfig) {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Basically, you are just re-writing the `collectRates` method of the parent class as per your requirements.

I couldn't get a chance to test the code, but it should give you some start for the point. My thoughts say  that if this code is in place, you should be able to switch off globally all shipping methods in the site if destination code is not present in the array of allowed codes.

Based upon your config file, this code should replace the original models block :

```
<models>
    <mpperproductshipping>
        <class>Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model</class>
    </mpperproductshipping>
    <shipping>
        <rewrite>
            <shipping>Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Shipping</shipping>
        </rewrite>
    </shipping>
</models>
```

And in class `Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Shipping` will go the above method. Don't forget to make that class a child of original `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping` class.

Comment: this is config.xml of our extension : config.xml = > http://pastebin.com/mftEuF4i

Comment: i followed this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/)  & changed the config.xml like this : http://pastebin.com/dc1bTCB7

Comment: No, that is invalid XML file. See my edit above in the question.

Comment: thanks, please check this : localdelivery.php = > http://pastebin.com/aFvMEXgV

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in `  : `$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');`

Comment: No, that is not correct. Code I provided is for a new file at location `app/code/local/Webkul/Mpperproductshipping/Model/Shipping.php`. Don't merge that with another file or code.

Comment: i didt that, is there anything else i need to do ? or did i missed somewhere, still i am facing same problem

means, once i enter wrong zip code, its not allowing. but when i come back and enter the wrong zip code, its restricting.

it should restrict for first time only.

Comment: updated config.xml file = > http://pastebin.com/1W4vuEt2

Comment: sorry, i missed some thing , now this error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in` line : `$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');`

Comment: shipping.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/CDv6TSEq , in line no.56 parse error is there.

Comment: please check [link](http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) allowed zip code : "560043" , restricted zip code : "000000"

Comment: Still incorrect, you don't need to have the above code in any existing file. Just create a new file at the place I mentioned and don't change anything else.

Comment: yes, i created new file shipping.phtml and added new file. i didt done any chnages for existing file.

Comment: but i got this error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in line : $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');`

Comment: Not shipping.phtml, new file will be a model called Shipping.php inside models folder of your module. Leave all files as they were.

Comment: sorry, i missly typed as phtml, but i added here : `app/code/local/Webkul/Mpperproductshipping/Model/Shipping.php`

Comment: parse error was because of session, i cleared it, now when i click on "continue" in "shipping information" step, its not going to next step.

Comment: What errors are you getting, check in logs. Add some debugging messages inside the code at various places and check till point your code is getting executed. All that information will help diagnose the issue further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37267/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-prateek).

Comment: @Prateek How can i get shipping zip code in checkout page?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here @Gem, do you have a clear question posted somewhere that I can see ?